# Using the Chain Rule to Prove Two Functions Are Equal

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I got stuck on a fairly simple exercise in differential calculus of multiple variables.
I shall present the exercise in it's entierty to provide some context:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be partially differentiable continuously in all of
> $\mathbb{R}^2$.
> It is also given  that:
> \begin{gather*}
>         \forall p \in \mathbb{R}^2 \\
>         (*) \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p) \\
>     \end{gather*}

In addition, it is given that for some $\alpha$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\alpha) \geq 0$ and that $\gamma = |\nabla f(\alpha)|$, so it is easily obtainable that $\nabla f(\alpha) = (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\gamma, \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\gamma)$
which is essentially what you were required to show in the first part of the question.

**My misunderstandings begin with the second part**, which is certainly the more challenging one, and is phrased thus:

> For all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ show that $f(x,y) = f(x + y, 0)$

Now, this is completely understandable intuitively by looking at $(*)$ - roughly means that what ever may be
the path we were to take, travelling in the $x$ direction will always have the same effect as travelling in the $y$ direction.

I am having trouble formalizing a proof... I wanted to use the chain rule and my professor assured me this is a valid way but -

1. What exactly should I derive? I think the following could lead somewhere:
   $\nabla(f(x, y) - f(x + y, 0))$
2. I am not sure how to derive the function in the right side of the equality using the chain-rule (this is a technique problem)
3. Even if it turns out that the gradients of both terms are equal, it doesn't necessarily
   mean that the functions are equal in all of $\mathbb{R}^2$, if I am not mistaken, so I am
   not quite sure what's the next step.

Many thanks for reading my question, hopefully it was phrased soundly enough.

Any suggestions or directions would be extremely appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: Fix $x,y$ and let $s=x+y$. Consider $F:\lambda\mapsto f(\lambda s,(1−\lambda)s)$ and use the MVT to get $F$ is constant, and so $F(1)=F(\frac{x}{s})$?

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you so much, and forgive me for the basic question, but how do we use the mean value theorem to prove $F$ is constant?

Comment: $F(\lambda_1)-F(\lambda_2)=F'(\xi)(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)=\dots=0$. You need the chain rule and the hypothesis $f_x=f_y$ to do the $\dots$ bit.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Ok, I think I got it. I would like to post an answer crediting you, but just to make sure before I post it- $\frac{dF}{d\lambda}(\xi) = (k, k) \cdot (s, -s) = 0$ where $k = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\xi)$ according to the chain rule and the hypothesis, is that correct? Thank you for your admirable patience.

Comment: Well that's the first $k$, the second is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\xi)$ when you use the chain rule, then separate step to use fact that these are equal by the hyp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a formalization of idea suggested by [@ancientmathematician](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092923/using-the-chain-rule-to-prove-two-functions-are-equal#comment8459351_4092923), thanks to his extremely helpful comments above.

Let $s = x + y$ for some $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Let us define:

\begin{gather*}
     F: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
     \lambda \rightarrow f(\lambda s, (1 - \lambda)s) \\ \\
     \varphi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \\
     \lambda \rightarrow (\lambda s, (1 - \lambda)s)
\end{gather*}

Of course, $F$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ by the chain rule, and by what we know about $f$.

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, by Lagrange's *Mean Value Theorem* we know $\exists \xi \in (a, b)$ s.t:

\begin{gather*}
    F(a) - F(b) = \frac{dF}{d\lambda}(\xi)\cdot(a - b)
\end{gather*}

Let us evaluate $\dfrac{dF}{d\lambda}$ in an arbitrary point using the *Chain Rule*:
\begin{align*}
        & \frac{dF}{d \lambda}(\lambda) = \nabla f(\lambda s, (1-\lambda)s) \cdot \nabla \varphi (\lambda) \\
        & = \Big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\lambda s, (1-\lambda)s), \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\lambda s, (1-\lambda)s)\Big)
        \cdot (s, -s)
\end{align*}

Now, given the hypothesis that $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}^2 : \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\alpha) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\alpha)$, the last term yields $0$ when the product is evaluated.
So we can claim $F(a) - F(b) = \frac{dF}{d\lambda}(\xi)\cdot(a - b) = 0$.

This is true $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, and therefore true for $a = \frac{x}{s}$ and $b = 1$. This specific case yields the following expression:
\begin{gather*}
    F(\frac{x}{s}) - F(1) = f(x, y) - f(x + y, 0) = 0
\end{gather*}

So, finally we have $\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : f(x,y) = f(x+y, 0)$.